# adding article effect a WordPress post or article

Tags: wordpress

can anyone share on how to go about adding article effects such as the ones being showed here http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/05/22/inspiration-for-article-intro-effects/ ; I'm planning to incorporate them on a wordpress platform, particularly on a single post template.

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Single.php for Display your single post

single.php is the single post page, the theme page for displaying just one post

Usually it in the theme folder /wp-content/themes/your-theme-name/

And Use Required Css / Jscript on Header.php or Footer.php for that article

Reference: http://www.heidicool.com/samplewordpress/theme-files/single-php/